# Using different letters to show statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance

[Table 3 of this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1474-919X.2012.01265.x/full) uses the letters A, B and C to show statistically significant differences between variables. I cannot understand what the letters A, B and C actually mean however. Can anyone explain which variables show statistically significant differences and which do not?

Table looks something like this:

```
  behaviour habitat1 habitat2 habitat3
1   feeding   0.32 A   0.33 A   0.34 B
2  roosting   0.47 A   0.45 A   0.46 A
3  swimming   0.09 A   0.11 A    0.1 A
4    flying   0.78 B    0.8 A   0.83 C
```

Comment: The paper is behind a pay wall. Can you replicate the table (or a simplified mock up of it)?

Comment: Usually such tables will have a footnote that represents significance levels.  Failing that, you might be able to look at the raw differences between variables and either assume equal errors or fine elsewhere in the paper what error terms were used.  From there you could try to derive the relative magnitudes of A, B, and C.  Failing that, you could contact the authors and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

For all variables with the same letter, the difference between the means is not statistically significant.

If two variables have different letters, they are significantly different.

The problem with this presentation is that the exact p-value remains unknown, unless included in the table notes or appendices.